# How to change encoding of Odoo 12 Qweb-text file

Tags: file, text, encoding, odoo, qweb

Odoo 12 uses Python 3.5+ whos default encoding is utf-8. I have a custom module to generate txt file through a template `report_type="qweb-text"` The generated and downloaded file on client's site is in utf-8 encoding respectively. I need it to be in cp1252. Any hints how this can be done? I was thinking of changing sys property on the fly as described here https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/odoo-10-text-file-from-odoo-have-encoding-issue-on-windows-146363 but have some worries what could happen. Any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You could try to encode the return value of model `ir.actions.report`'s method `render_qweb_text`. I don't like the the forum answer, because it is like cracking a nut with a sledgehammer.

Comment: I tried this:  ''' def render_qweb_text(self, docids, data=None):
        if not data:
            data = {}
        data.setdefault('report_type', 'text')
        data = self._get_rendering_context(docids, data)
  #     data = data.decode('cp1252')
        return self.render_template(self.report_name, data), 'text' '''

Comment: ```def render_qweb_text(self, docids, data=None):
        if not data:
            data = {}
        data.setdefault('report_type', 'text')
        data = self._get_rendering_context(docids, data)
  #     data = data.decode('cp1252')
        return self.render_template(self.report_name, data), 'text' ``` but ```data``` object is of type dict and doesn't accept ```decode``` Any other thoughts?